# Minimizing a function with vectors

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, regression, statistical-inference

This is a part of a problem that I'm having, and I'm unclear how to do this particular step. I'm dealing with a ridged regression and I need to minimize the equation

$$\sum (Y_i - \beta^Tx_i)^2 + \lambda\sum\beta_j^2$$

The question says I need to find $\beta$ that minimizes this and I'm not sure how to do that because I have a vector.

How do I do this?

Comment: What would you do, if $\beta$ wasn't a vector?

Comment: er just differentiate normally?

Comment: Exactly, differentiate and set it equal to zero. Now that you have a vector, just do that for each component and you should get a system of equations to solve.

Comment: wait but how then do I deal with the beta i in the second sigma?

Comment: **Hint** $\sum_j\beta_j^2=\mathbf{\beta}^T\mathbf{\beta}$.

Comment: I am not sure that hint really helps. If you have $\sum \beta_j^2$ and differentiate with respect to $\beta_j$ this simply becomes $2\beta_j$

Answer (score 1):

Lets us define 
$$ E = \sum (Y_i -\beta^T x_i)^2+ \lambda \sum \beta_j^2$$
And we want to find optimal values for $\beta$. Thus we take the derivative of $E$ with respect to $\beta$ (Note that $x_{ij}$ means component $j$ of vector $x_i$).
\begin{align}
\nabla_\beta E &= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1}\\ ..\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_n}\end{pmatrix}E \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1}(\sum (Y_i -\beta^T x_i)^2+ \lambda \sum \beta_j^2)\\ ..\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_n}(\sum (Y_i -\beta^T x_i)^2+ \lambda \sum \beta_j^2) \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \sum -2x_{i1}(Y_i -\beta^T x_i)+ 2\lambda \beta_1\\ ..\\ \sum -2x_{in}(Y_i -\beta^T x_i)+ 2\lambda \beta_n \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \sum -2x_{i1}Y_i +\sum 2x_{i1} \beta^T x_i+ 2\lambda \beta_1\\ ..\\ \sum -2x_{in}Y_i +\sum 2x_{in} \beta^T x_i+ 2\lambda \beta_n\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \sum -2x_{i1}Y_i +2\sum \beta_j \sum x_{i1}  x_{ij}+ 2\lambda \beta_1\\ ..\\ \sum -2x_{in}Y_i +2\sum \beta_j \sum x_{in}  x_{ij}+ 2\lambda \beta_n\end{pmatrix} \\
&= A\beta +r 
\end{align}
Where 
\begin{align}
A = 2\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda +\sum x_{i1}x_{i1} & \sum x_{i1}x_{i2} &  \sum x_{i1}x_{i3} & ... & \sum x_{i1}x_{in} \\
\sum x_{i2}x_{i1}
 & \lambda + \sum x_{i2}x_{i2} & \sum x_{i2}x_{i3} & ... & \sum x_{i2}x_{in} \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & \\
\sum x_{in}x_{i1}
 &  \sum x_{in}x_{i2} & \sum x_{in}x_{i3} & ... &\lambda+ \sum x_{in}x_{in} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
And 
\begin{align}
r = -2\begin{pmatrix}\sum x_{i1}Y_i \\ ..\\\sum x_{in}Y_i \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
To obtain a minima, we need to solve $A\beta+r=0$. This gives you $\beta$.

**I really encourage you, to check my indices and sums**, as I did this rather quick.

Comment: I would appreciate it, if someone could doble check my calculation. Thanks in advance!